# Custom connector not found in Azure logic app(Standard)

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, data-gateway, azure-logic-app-standard

I added a logic app custom connector resource to connect to on premise HTTP API. But I'm not able to find it in logic app actions,

[image]

I tried creating consumption logic app and it showed up there.
[image]

Not getting in standard logic app for some reason. I tried searching with different keywords like custom connector and name of connectors. No results. Also tried to include this action from code view . It got added, but the logic app stops after executing trigger only.

Both my connector and logic app are in same region as per documentation. Can someone let me know why it is not showing up in standard logic app actions?

Comment: Are you trying form azure protal or from vs code ?

Comment: From azure portal. @Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently we don’t support invoking the [customer connector from Logic App standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/single-tenant-overview-compare#changed-limited-unavailable-or-unsupported-capabilities). This is something product team are planning to support but no ETA yet.

> Custom managed connectors currently aren't currently supported.

Answer (score 0):

As Mayank mentioned, custom connectors are not yet supported for Logic app standard version. Couple of possible workaround solutions are:

1.Try built-in connector extensibility  - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure/azure-logic-apps-running-anywhere-built-in-connector/ba-p/1921272

2.Use a consumption logic app for integrating custom connectors and invoke it from your standard logic app.

Answer (score 0):

Custom connector support is coming soon to Logic Apps Standard.

By creating a new custom connector and manually adding it to the connection json and manually crafting the workflow code view you can make this work today. Once you do this some of the UI will work, full support coming soon.