# Missing Logic Apps connector action from Logic Apps Standard Workflow when creating nested Logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I created a Logic Apps Standard, a workflow, and a trigger of `Request When a HTTP request is received`, like below by following the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint#create-a-callable-endpoint

[image]

However, I also want to create `logic apps: Choose a Logic Apps workflow` following the link below, but **it is not available** shown above.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint#create-nested-logic-apps

Image from the link above for comparison.
[image]

**Questions**

How to make it available under Logic Apps std or other versions apart from Consumption?

Why is it that many connectors that are available in Consumption are not available in the Standard plan?

Refs:

[Why does Logic App Standard Plan have missing connection trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69573749/why-does-logic-app-standard-plan-have-missing-connection-trigger)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to create an simple logic app in ***standard plan*** and unable to get this connector called ***`Logic apps: Choose a Logic Apps workflow`***

[image]

And tried the same with ***consumption plan*** and its showing there .
[image]

So you can try with the same [***`MS DOC`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint#create-a-callable-endpoint) that you are following with ***Logic app- Consumption***

For more information please refer this ***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***: [***Single-tenant versus multi-tenant and integration service environment for Azure Logic Apps***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/single-tenant-overview-compare)

Comment: Thanks. Pls read my update on OP.

Comment: Could you please refer this MS DOC:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/single-tenant-overview-compare .

Comment: As stated in the above MS DOC:-"The Consumption resource type runs in the multi-tenant Azure Logic Apps or integration service environment, while the Standard resource type runs in single-tenant Azure Logic Apps environment." Also you can refer this ms doc:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-pricing#trigger-and-action-operations-in-the-standard-model

Comment: Do you have info on why many connectors that are available in Consumption are not available in the Standard plan?

Comment: AFAIK, we can not do the same as on consumption in standard based on the  given MS DOC.

Comment: I have tried with ISE , but we can not do that same feature which is available in consumption(as ISE is for consumption). So for pricing details , Could you please refer the above given Microsoft document. We have to use consumption for those feature.

Comment: You can refer this SO THREAD: [Custom connector not found in Azure logic app(Standard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69324490/custom-connector-not-found-in-azure-logic-appstandard?rq=1) ,

Comment: Otherwise you could use the HTTP-connector to POST data from your first logic app as long as you don't have too long response time from the underlying logic app.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly note that we have something called managed connectors which are used in LA consumption and something called builtin connectors and can be used with standard logic apps.

The built in connectors are running in the LA standard process. While the managed are in a different process.

The list of actions which are available in managed connectors are not always available in the built in connectors.

Still you can use the managed connectors in the LA standard site.